# Good for Wireless, Network, etc.. But what about Proprietary video drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, data-recovery, proprietary, restricted

I'm looking for a similar quest, But instead for a Proprietary Video driver.
I'm running 16.04LTS, and my machine has a NVIDEA GTX card. Occasionally, the internet service goes wonky at home, so I'll downgrade to the generic X.ORG Nouveau driver, shut-down, eject the main boot drive, and take it with me with a Laptop & an external dock, to a local coffee shop (Better than hauling the whole desktop server to there.) I'll boot the drive externally on the laptop, run the updates (apt-get update/upgrade ,) power-down, bring the drive back home, re-insert to the main machine, then reboot.. BUT.... I cannot return to the proprietary driver... resulting, slugging running video.   Can the proprietary drivers be recovered,  and reinstalled?  Or, do I simply have to wait til the Internet is back up local to the server?  Thanks, Stephen (gelfling6)

Comment: How did you install nVidia driver? If you install from nVidia you have to run commands to re-configure it for every new kernel. Best to always install from Ubuntu repository. But you may not get auto update if laptop not also nVidia. Not sure exact command. `sudo service lightdm stop` & 
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current` or your specific version of nvidia?

Comment: The driver was originally installed via the System Settings  -> Software & Updates  -> Additional Drivers, the drivers are loaded via NVIDEA that method.  I was able to restore it when the WiFi at home was active again (shared, and yes, Legally.), but, yet again, it's gone down.. (wonky router/Firewall used, and the router is not easily accessible.)

Comment: Check if you downloaded newer kernel & then you do not have nVidia driver. `dkms status` It may be easier just to reinstall as it has to be reconfigured into kernel with dkms. See what versions are available: `ubuntu-drivers devices` and auto install recommended (same as System Setting screens you used). `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: Okay, I don't have the drive handy.. the 'flakey' WiFi is back up again (Hotspotsystems firewall.. SHEESH!) and I was able to get it back by re-installing the driver again.. But, just for gall, I'll pull the drive, and give this a shot tomorrow.  Thanks!  Stephen